# Let $f \in \mathcal C_0$ and $\varepsilon >0$. Is there an explicit construction of $g\in\mathcal C_c^\infty$ such that $\|f-g\|_\infty <\varepsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, smooth-functions, weierstrass-approximation

Let $\mathcal C_0 (\mathbb R^d)$ be the space of real-valued continuous functions on $\mathbb R^d$ that vanish at infinity. Let $\mathcal C_c^\infty (\mathbb R^d)$  be the space of real-valued smooth functions on $\mathbb R^d$ with compact supports. By Stone–Weierstrass theorem, $\mathcal C_c^\infty (\mathbb R^d)$ is dense in $\mathcal C_0 (\mathbb R^d)$ w.r.t. the topology of $\| \cdot \|_\infty$.

> Fix $f \in \mathcal C_0 (\mathbb R^d)$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Is there an explicit construction of $g \in \mathcal C_c^\infty (\mathbb R^d)$ such that $\|f-g\|_\infty <\varepsilon$?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: Bernstein polynomials.

Comment: You may have already tried it and it may not work, which is why I'm including it only as a comment but: if your original $f$ vanishes at infinity (if I understand it in the sense you mean it), then you can find a big enough (closed) ball $B$ around $0$ such that $|| f ||_\infty < \varepsilon$ outside of it? Then, you can set $g$ to be $f$ on $B$, and $0$ outside it (and multiply with an appropriate bump function to make it smooth)

Comment: Convolution with a bump function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1)
Let $\psi(x)$ be a smooth function satisfying $0\leq \psi(x)\leq 1$ and
$$\begin{align}
\psi(x)&=1,\quad-1\leq x\leq 1,\\
\psi(x)&=0,\quad |x|\geq 2.
\end{align}$$
Denote $\psi_\delta=\psi(\frac{x}{\delta})$. For any $f\in\mathcal C_0(\mathbb R)$,
$$f\cdot \psi_\delta\in \mathcal C_c(\mathbb R),\quad \Vert f-f\cdot \psi_\delta\Vert_\infty\leq\sup_{|X|\geq \delta} |f(x)|\to 0, \quad \delta\to \infty.$$

(2)
Let $\phi(x)$ be a smooth function with support in $(-1,1)$ satisfying
$$\begin{align}
\int \phi=1.
\end{align}$$
Then $\phi_\varepsilon(x)=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\phi(\frac{x}{\varepsilon})$ is a family of good kernels. For $g\in C_c(\mathbb R)$, we have
$$g*\phi_\varepsilon\in \mathcal C_c^\infty(\mathbb R),\quad \Vert g-g*\phi_\varepsilon\Vert_\infty\to 0,\quad \epsilon\to 0.$$

Combine (1) and (2) together, you will get the function required. The general case for $\mathbb R^d$ is similar.